# RDLC - calling a Subreport a variable number of times from a Report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have a report designed in RDLC that has a Dataset consisting of a set of integer UserID values. The report consists of a one-column table, with each row grouped by UserID. Inside each cell is a subreport generated from the UserID. The subreport is also designed in RDLC from two separate datasets, each of which is generated based on the UserID.

How do I design the subreport to generate the appropriate information for each Parent row's UserID?

I don't see how it can be done on the parent report side, as the method defined in SubreportProcessingEventHandler appears to be called just once, rather than once for each UserID's Subreport.

I assume it has to be done in the Subreport's ascx.cs file - but where would I put it? Is there a predetermined method name to use, or do I call the method from the parent somehow?

Is what I am describing even possible?

Comment: make a long story short ! Do you pass parameter UserID to subreport ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer - at least, the one that works when I do it - is, the SubreportProcessingEventHandler is, in fact, called once for each UserID, so the UserID is passed to the handler as a parameter, and the subreport's data sets are built within the handler using that UserID.